# Reading data using igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to learn igraph in Python and have a csv file that contains network data in the format below,

```
1   2
1   3
2   4
3   5
```

and here is how I import it using igraph

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph.Read_Ncol('data.csv',directed=True)
```

But I get this error

```
SystemError: <built-in method Read_Ncol of type object at 0x0000027F555A3868> returned NULL without setting an error
```

I am not sure why it is saying returned NULL.

Comment: this will only work if the file is in the current working directory. You might try `import os`  `os.listdir(".")` to insure that you are pointing where you think you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. It looks like igraph might only accept specific file extensions.  The file might need be named `'data.ncol'`.
2. If it is an *actual* .csv file, you will need to replace the commas with whitespace to adhere to the .ncol format.